# Query Param not working getting stripped off

Tags: java, javascript

I am passing a url in client side as http://xyz.org/audio?s=0.8717912845313549&download=true.
And in server side I am searching for the flag download by passing Query Parameter in my function getAudio().
Here is the code
public response getAudio(@QueryParam("download") @DefaultValue("false") boolean download) 
Thus my always default value remains false even though my url contains downlaod=true.
Is the query param I am passing is correct?
Or do I need to make any change.

Answer (score 1):

You'r missing the question mark

http://xyz.org/audio?s=0.8717912845313549&download=true

Comment: My bad there is question mark in URL but while typing here I missed it.